# How to transfer images from wcf ksoap2 to android

Tags: c#, java, android, wcf, arraylist

I am trying to send images from wcf ksoap2 to android. 
At wcf side I have converted all images into byte array and stored them in an ArrayList. 
At android side I fill the ArrayList from wcf response.
Now the problem is byte array is not receiving properly and byte array is not converting into Image/BufferedImage.

Here is my code

```
        byt = new byte[4096];
        byt = (byte[]) al.get(5);
        //Image im;
        BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = null;
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byt);

        try {
            bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);
            //ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "jpg", new File(
            //      "c:/new-darksouls.jpg"));               

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

al is my ArrayList.

Comment: have you problem in android code side or .net side?

Comment: I am having problem at android side.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String prepareImage() {
        if (tempPath == null ) {
            return "";
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempPath, options);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 50, 50, true);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        //bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, baos);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);

        byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();

        String imageString = com.size4u.utils.Base64
                .encodeBytes(byteArray);
        bitmap = null;
        System.gc();
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
        return imageString;
    }
```

Comment: I can't get it. I want to convert byte[] to Image/BufferedImage

Comment: tempPath is your image path

Comment: this function returns imagestring that store bytes and this string pass in to webservice.

Comment: i guess you didn't understand. I want to transfer images from wcf to android.. not from android. I have converted images to byte array at wcf sides and now I want to receive that byte array at android.

Comment: please check this...
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata , 0, bitmapdata .length);
Returns The decoded bitmap, or null if the image could not be decode.

Comment: bitmap data is your byte data